# facebook chat API

Tags: php, facebook, chat

I have an app, and what I want is to be able to write a FB chat message to all users that use this app and are online at the moment. Is that possible? Possibly, to their friends too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/

Comment: I don't understand from this document whether I need FB users to give me their username/password in order for me to be able to send them/use those users to send their friends a message or is it enough for those users to be authorized to use my App?

Comment: In which manner? send users of my App message or send messages to friends of my app users? or both.

Comment: You answered your own question: both. If you need some kind of chat like this, you'll need to write your own.